# Using an "IF" statement based on the existence of custom field

Tags: php, custom-field

I wish to use a function which is run only when a specific custom field is available.

Something like:

```
if (custom_field_x_exists("name_of_the_custom_field")) :
                       <Do some things>;
        endif;
```

How might it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help

```
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name_of_the_custom_field', true ) ) :
    // Do something
endif;
```